# Adding several deform points in one circular object (belt)

Tags: modifiers, sculpting, photorealism

I am trying to go to the "next level" of modeling, and trying to sculpt the CGTrader challenge.

So far I was handling it good but, wanting to achieve realism, I got stuck at the point of how to make a smooth deform along all the rivets/buttons of this stool belt (as the attached picture).[image]

I want to make the "pressure" deform effect using either array modifier or using the button-objects themselves.   I have not found anything related to it, since it is very specific effect.

Which would be the quickest way to select all the deform points quickly, without having to do them individually.

Thank you all for this fantastic community.

Comment: I think that for the small deformation around those buttons I would try using a normal map, might be easier than dealing with such fine geometry.

Comment: You could use an array + simple deform (like modeling a tire) or go with radial symmetry in sculpt mode to name two more ways.

Answer (score 0):

I might try attaching the buttons to a flat, heavily subdivided belt, and then selecting all the buttons, and scaling down with proportional edit turned on.